# Want to get button work by using bootstrap program

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[This image has button on right side in nav-bar. This button is my main issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfM6Q.png)

[Here, in this picture you will see along with the Website title menu I have created 3 tab like Page1, PAge2, and Page3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNxOk.png)

Problem which I have it is: Button on right side will appear when browser window page maximize and disappear tab's call Page 1 to Page3. I want to get button work by clicking on button than Page 1 to Page 3 tabs appear on page if it's disappear. Here is my code below and I am working on bootstrap and it already downloaded into my folder.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

       <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
                <!-- Bootstrap -->
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
                     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                     <![endif]-->

            <style>

                .box {
                    background-color:#d3d3d3;
                    border: 1px solid ;

                      }


            </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>

           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">                                                    
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>                                                   
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                      
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                      
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                                                                        
           </button> 

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="active"><a href="">Page 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <h1>Our Bootstrap Page</h1>

        <form>

          <input type="text" />


        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to work on the below code. This is the bootstrap starter template.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Website</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

> datatoggle="collapse"

To:

```
data-toggle="collapse"
```